# Ruby on Rails Gem general information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am wondering what are gems? Coming from C++, Java, its seem they are packages which form a class or a plugin i should say.

- But how do they work? Most of them are on github to be shared but what happens when i place them in my gemfile and run bundle install?
- Do i place the current version into a temporary file in the localhost or his the server fetching the information all the time from the github?7
- If they are on the server can i modify the gem somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gems are libraries; collections of Ruby files, descriptors, tests, and whatever else the library has.

They're installed locally when you do a `bundle install`.

Use `bundle show [gem_name]` to see where a gem was installed.

I'd recommend using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or an equivalent to manage different sets of gems/rubies, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is nice place to find a gem that fits your project.
This free [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler) will teach you how to manage your project gems.